# Is my WPF element visible on the screen or hidden by another window of any application

Tags: wpf, winapi

How do I know if an element in my WPF application, is hidden by another window of any application

Here are my example how I get information about open windows on the screen. For example: Is my application on top.

(the basic code I am learned in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19529/Is-My-Application-on-Top)

```
 Declare Function GetTopWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetTopWindow" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer
    Declare Function GetNextWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindow" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wFlag As Integer) As Integer
    Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32" Alias "IsWindowVisible" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Boolean
    Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
    Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowRect" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef pwi As Rect) As Boolean

    Function IsOnTop(ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim i As Integer = GetTopWindow(0)
        Dim x As Integer = 1
        Dim s As String

        Do
            i = GetNextWindow(i, 2)  ' Find next window in Z-order
            If i = hwnd Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                If i = 0 Then           ' Never find any window match the input handle
                    Return False
                End If
            End If

            If IsWindowVisible(i) = True Then
                s = Space(256)
                If GetWindowText(i, s, 255) <> 0 Then
                    ' Very important to prevent confusing of BalloonTips and ContextMenuStrips
                    x += 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        ' x is Z-order number

        If x = 1 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function GetWindowText(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As String
        Dim s = Space(256)
        GetWindowText(hWnd, s, 255)
        Return s.ToString()
    End Function

    Function GetRectWindow(hwnd As Integer) As Rect
        Dim rc As Rect
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, rc)
        Return rc
    End Function
```

I need to know the width & height of other windows. Without this data, I still can not know about an element if it is hidden to the user. For example, in my application, I have a window that contains two DataGrid's, one of which may be hidden by other application.

The problem is, Although the GetRectWindow method returns this data, but, for example, it gives in Width property = 4.09332988076806E-311 and it should be 350. To my knowledge, it uses Twips unit. I converted it to pixel unit, but the result I got is an infinite number -0.

Comment: Here you an example [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584154/is-my-wpf-element-visible-on-the-screen-or-hidden-by-another-window-of-any-appli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584154/is-my-wpf-element-visible-on-the-screen-or-hidden-by-another-window-of-any-appli). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way :

- Compute bounds of your visual relative to root visual (Visual.TransformToAncestor)
- Compute bounds of your visual relative to screen (native GetWindowRect & GetClientRect)
- Enumerate all top level windows (native EnumWindows)
- Check for each windows if it's visible and if it overlaps the bounds of your visual (native GetWindowRect)

Comment: First, thanks for your suggestion.
The solution proposed is great, but how do I know what the width and height of the top window.
Without this data, I still can not know about an element if it is hidden to the user.
For example, in my application, I have a window that contains two DataGrid's, one of which may be hidden by other application. And it's that I need to know.
I would be happy even if you attach an example of code.

Comment: @Haim Window.Width & Window.Height ?

Comment: I need to know the with & height of other application on the screen.

Comment: @Haim EnumWindows list all widows (other applications included), and GetWindowRect allow you to get their position and size.

Comment: The GetWindowRect does not return the correct width.

Comment: @Haim, GetWindowRect do not return width, it returns coordinates of top left and bottom right window bounds relative to desktop's top left corner.

Comment: Right, it returns coordinates of top left and bottom right window bounds relative to desktop's top left corner, but, for example, it gives in Right property = 4.09332988076806E-311 and it should be 0.
To my knowledge, it uses Twips unit. I converted it to pixel unit, but the result I got is an infinite number -0.
thanks you

Comment: @Haim RECT.right is a LONG, how can it have a floating point value ?

Comment: @Haim Why calling GetWindowInfo with a rect ?

Comment: Sorry, I retract. This is my code, and the result as mentioned above:

    Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowRect" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef pwi As Rect) As Boolean

    Function GetRectWindow(hwnd As Integer) As Rect
        Dim rc As Rect
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, rc)
        Return rc
    End Function